# Create a photo collection in a Symfony form

Tags: php, symfony

I already asked a question here [Symfony 4 - VichUploaderBundle - file input not rendered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51314998/symfony-4-vichuploaderbundle-file-input-not-rendered?noredirect=1#comment89657419_51314998), but I didn't have an answer that could help me. I retry my luck a few days later because I'm still blocked.

I get this error when I try to create a photo collection :

> Too few arguments to function Vich\UploaderBundle\Form\Type\VichFileType::__construct(), 0 passed in C:\wamp64\www\my_project\vendor\symfony\form\FormRegistry.php on line 92 and at least 3 expected

easy_admin.yml (it creates the photo collection) :

```
easy_admin:
        entities:
        FicheProduit:
            class: App\Entity\FicheProduit
                    - { property: 'photos', type: 'collection', type_options: { entry_type: 'App\Form\PhotoType', by_reference: false, allow_add: true, allow_delete: true }}
```

vich_uploader.yml :

```
vich_uploader:
    db_driver: orm
    mappings:
        fiche_produit_photo:
            uri_prefix: /images/products
            upload_destination: '%kernel.project_dir%/public/build/images/products'
            namer: vich_uploader.namer_origname
            inject_on_load: false
            delete_on_update: true
            delete_on_remove: true
```

FicheProduit.php :

```
<?php

declare(strict_types = 1);

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * Class FicheProduit
 * 
 * @package App\Entity
 *
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class FicheProduit
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", options={"unsigned":true}, nullable=false)
     *
     * @var int
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Photo", mappedBy="ficheProduit", cascade={"persist", "remove"}, orphanRemoval=true)
     *
     * @Assert\Valid()
     *
     * @var Photo[]|ArrayCollection
     */
    protected $photos;

    /**
     * FicheProduit constructor.
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->photos = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * @param int $id
     */
    public function setId(int $id): void
    {
        $this->id = $id;
    }

    /**
     * @return Photo[]|ArrayCollection
     */
    public function getPhotos()
    {
        return $this->photos;
    }

    /**
     * @param Photo[]|ArrayCollection $photos
     */
    public function setPhotos($photos): void
    {
        $this->photos = $photos;
    }

    /**
     * Add photo
     *
     * @param Photo $photo
     *
     * @return FicheProduit
     */
    public function addPhoto(Photo $photo)
    {
        $photo->setProduct($this);
        $this->photos[] = $photo;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove photo
     *
     * @param Photo $photo
     */
    public function removePhoto(Photo $photo)
    {
        $this->photos->removeElement($photo);
    }
}
```

Photo.php :

```
<?php

declare(strict_types = 1);

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Entity\Traits\TimestampableTrait;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File;
use Vich\UploaderBundle\Mapping\Annotation as Vich;

/**
 * Class Photo
 *
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="fiche_produit_photos")
 * @Vich\Uploadable
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 *
 * @package App\Entity
 */
class Photo
{
    use TimestampableTrait;

    /**
     * @var int
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Photo", inversedBy="photos")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     *
     * @var FicheProduit
     */
    protected $ficheProduit;

    /**
     * NOTE: This is not a mapped field of entity metadata, just a simple property.
     *
     * @Vich\UploadableField(mapping="fiche_produit_photo", fileNameProperty="fileName", originalName="originalName", mimeType="mimeType", size="size")
     *
     * @var File
     */
    protected $file;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="size", type="integer", nullable=true)
     *
     * @var int
     */
    protected $size;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(nullable=true)
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $mimeType;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(nullable=true)
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $originalName;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $fileName;

    /**
     * Photo constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
    }

    /**
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * @return FicheProduit
     */
    public function getFicheProduit(): FicheProduit
    {
        return $this->ficheProduit;
    }

    /**
     * @param FicheProduit $ficheProduit
     */
    public function setFicheProduit(FicheProduit $ficheProduit): void
    {
        $this->ficheProduit = $ficheProduit;
    }

    /**
     * @return int
     */
    public function getSize()
    {
        return $this->size;
    }

    /**
     * @param int $size
     */
    public function setSize($size)
    {
        $this->size = $size;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getMimeType()
    {
        return $this->mimeType;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $mimeType
     */
    public function setMimeType($mimeType)
    {
        $this->mimeType = $mimeType;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getOriginalName()
    {
        return $this->originalName;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $originalName
     */
    public function setOriginalName($originalName)
    {
        $this->originalName = $originalName;
    }

    /**
     * @return File
     */
    public function getFile()
    {
        return $this->file;
    }

    /**
     * @param File $file
     */
    public function setFile(File $file = null)
    {
        $this->file = $file;
        if ($file) {
            // It is required that at least one field changes if you are using doctrine
            // otherwise the event listeners won't be called and the file is lost
            $this->updatedAt = new \DateTimeImmutable();
        }
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getFileName()
    {
        return $this->fileName;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $fileName
     */
    public function setFileName($fileName)
    {
        $this->fileName = $fileName;
    }
}
```

TimestampableTrait.php :

```
<?php

declare(strict_types = 1);

namespace App\Entity\Traits;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * Trait TimestampableTrait
 *
 * @package App\Entity\Traits
 */
trait TimestampableTrait
{
    /**
     * @var \DateTime $createdAt Created at
     *
     * @Assert\Type("\DateTime")
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", nullable=false)
     */
    protected $createdAt;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime $updatedAt Updated at
     *
     * @Assert\Type("\DateTime")
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", nullable=false)
     */
    protected $updatedAt;

    /**
     * Get created at
     *
     * @return \DateTime Created at
     */
    public function getCreatedAt()
    {
        return $this->createdAt;
    }

    /**
     * Set created at
     *
     * @param \DateTime $createdAt Created at
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setCreatedAt(\DateTime $createdAt)
    {
        $this->createdAt = $createdAt;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get updated at
     *
     * @return \DateTime Updated at
     */
    public function getUpdatedAt()
    {
        return $this->updatedAt;
    }

    /**
     * Set updated at
     *
     * @param \DateTime $updatedAt Updated at
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setUpdatedAt(\DateTime $updatedAt)
    {
        $this->updatedAt = $updatedAt;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\PrePersist
     */
    public function prePersist()
    {
        $this->setCreatedAt(new \DateTime());
        $this->setUpdatedAt(new \DateTime());
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\PreUpdate
     */
    public function preUpdate()
    {
        $this->setUpdatedAt(new \DateTime());
    }
}
```

PhotoType.php :

```
<?php

declare(strict_types = 1);

namespace App\Form;

use App\Entity\Photo;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Vich\UploaderBundle\Form\Type\VichFileType;

/**
 * Class PhotoType
 *
 * @package App\Form
 */
class PhotoType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('originalName', TextType::class, ['required' => false ])
            ->add('file', VichFileType::class, [
                'required' => false,
                'allow_delete' => false,
                'download_uri' => true,
                'download_label' => true
            ]);
        ;
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolver $resolver
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Photo::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

No need to send me official Symfony documentation or bundles that I use, I have read them before and I have also gone to issues on Github. I didn't find anything to solve my problem. :/

Is a genius here ?

I despair .. thank you very much in advance for your help

Comment: error clearly states there is missing DI arguments, if we look at config file [form.xml](https://github.com/dustin10/VichUploaderBundle/blob/aad4ccceb5bc6d832f27a025334334b159073f80/Resources/config/form.xml), there is all injection arguments added, so it is probably not loaded here [VichUploaderExtension.php](https://github.com/dustin10/VichUploaderBundle/blob/bacd247fdeff1380eecf38658e259929dc5976ca/DependencyInjection/VichUploaderExtension.php) on 74 line. Debug this and check whether from.xml is loaded or not.

Comment: I have this error when I add form.xml in services.yml . "Bundle "VichUploaderBundle" does not exist or it is not enabled. Maybe you forgot to add it in the registerBundles() method of your App\Kernel.php file? in @VichUploaderBundle/Resources/config/form.xml (which is being imported from "C:\wamp64\www\blh_wines\config/services.yaml"). Make sure the "VichUploaderBundle/Resources/config/form.xml" bundle is correctly registered and loaded in the application kernel class. If the bundle is registered, make sure the bundle path "@VichUploaderBundle/Resources/config/form.xml" is not empty."

Comment: does your kernel file contain this bundle?

Comment: It was not there, I just added it. But now I have this error :  InvalidConfigurationException
The child node "db_driver" at path "vich_uploader" must be configured.

Comment: in what directory is your vich_uploader.xml file? it should be in config/packages/vich_uploader.yaml or app/config/config.yml

Comment: vich_uploader.yml is in config/packages/vich_uploader.yml

Comment: I managed to correct the problem by renaming vich_uploader.yml to vich_uploader.yaml :O thank you very much for your help